# How to get tooltips to work within my Chart.js BoxPlot extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, chart.js, jsbin

G'day, sirs!

**Background**:

- Needed a simple BoxPlot extension for Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/), see Code here: http://jsbin.com/yekimavemu/2/edit?html,js,console,output <strike>(Not working currently, see problems, below)</strike>
- Took the StackBar community extension as a base, see here: https://github.com/Regaddi/Chart.StackedBar.js
- Got everything working within a few days[image]

**Problems**:

1. <strike>Made a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/nenaguqote/1/edit?html,js,console,output  --> Don't get it to work! Don't know why I get an "TypeError: (intermediate value).BoxPlot is not a function"; Works fine on Desktop version</strike>
2. The actual problem I have is getting the Tooltip feature to work. It works fine in the StackBar extension. I could not figure it out, what to change to make it work with my BoxPlot.

So if anyone can offer help in one of the two problems, would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
  Alex

Comment: for your first error it is because you are trying to call the BoxPlot chart type before the actual BoXplot has been declared as a new chart type. Just move the graph creation to after this deceleration and it works fine (well apart from problem 2) http://jsbin.com/nuhuketita/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Do you have a github repository for your box plot project? I need to draw some box plot graphs too.

Comment: Nope, just the code snippets in the above jsbin (http://jsbin.com/yekimavemu/2/edit?html,js,console,output).... Checked it, still works...